# Creating a raster stack of algorithms using nested loops to iterate through all possible band combination

Tags: r, algorithm, loops, apply, raster

All,

I am not able to directly stack these images inside of the loop. My only work around was to write each results then stack the images after the loop was completed. I would like to find an apply function that would allow me to do the same thing and I need to find a way to stack these rasters inside the loop instead of creating intermediate data by saving the output.

Any insight into this process would appreciated!

```
# Create function
Loop <- function(X,B1,B2){
  S2_ext <- extent(S2) # Create raster template
  2BDA_Stack <- raster(S2_ext)
   for(i in B1){
     for(j in B2){
      2BDA <- X[[i]]/X[[j]]
      2BDA_Stack <- stack(2BDA_Stack, 2BDA)
# I WANT TO REMOVE THIS STEP
      writeRaster(x = 2BDA,
                  filename= paste("...",'Chl_2BDA_',i,j),
                  format = "GTiff", # save as a tif
                  datatype='FLT4S', # save as a float
                  overwrite = T) #Overwrites same named file
     }
   }
}

#Run Function
2BDA_Loop(X=S2,B1=1:6,B2=1:6)
```

Comment: Not sure about your exact problem here... what does `2BDA_Stack <- stack(2BDA_Stack, 2BDA)`? You don't use it anymore or return it.

Comment: @MartinGal  I am not able to extract the results of the loop out of the loop without saving them individually. I would like for the raster indices to be stacked so the results are a stacked raster with each band representing one iteration of the formula of  `X[[i]]/X[[j]]` which in this case is 36 (i = 6, j =6).

Comment: Do you want your function to return `2BDA`? If yes, use `return(2BDA)`. If no, please make a reproducible example with a sample input and your desired output (based on this input).

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Using return(2BDA_Stack) after the second closed curly brace, allows me to see that the file is created but still unable to save that file in my working environment.

Comment: Assign it to a variable:`my_var <- Loop(X=S2,B1=1:6,B2=1:6)`?